# Is there a way to use gspread to select all the cells that have content?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

I have a google worksheet that is constantly being added to via a google form. I am trying to use gspread to take the content provided by the form and transfer it to a separate spreadsheet. The problem I have run into is selecting all the cells that have content, as in they are non-blank. Ideally I would like to only grab the new content, but I thought just grabbing the entire sheet may be easier to start with.

Is there any way to accomplish this with gspread?

Comment: Visit <https://stackoverflow.com/a/52519126/3129642> for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this in python, it puts all the non-blank rows in a list of dictionaries:

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open('test1').sheet1
ss_list = wks.get_all_records()
print (ss_list)
```